# How to move two images using keyboard keys at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Below my code is of just the start of a game and I can only move one image at a time. How do I change it so that I can move both, one with the arrow keys and one with the WASD keys? I only need to move it horizontally.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()
root.title('Plane Wars Blitz')
root.geometry("1200x800")

w = 1200
h = 800
x = w/2
y = h/2

my_canvas = Canvas(root,width = w,height = h, bg = "light blue")
my_canvas.pack(pady=20)

ship1=PhotoImage(file="shipup.png")
ship2=PhotoImage(file="shipdown.png")

ship1image = my_canvas.create_image(600,700,image=ship1)
ship2image = my_canvas.create_image(600,100,image=ship2)

def left1(event):
    x = -20
    y = 0
    my_canvas.move(ship1image,x,y)

def right1(event):
    x = 20
    y = 0
    my_canvas.move(ship1image,x,y)

def left2(event):
    x = -20
    y = 0
    my_canvas.move(ship2image,x,y)

def right2(event):
    x = 20
    y = 0
    my_canvas.move(ship2image,x,y)


root.bind("<Left>",left1)
root.bind("<Right>",right1)
root.bind("<a>",left2)
root.bind("<s>",right2)
    

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code for you, but idea.

1. Bind KeyPress, KeyRelease to all keys, like <Left>, <Right>, <a>, <s>
2. Callback for all the binding just to record key pressed or released, and some other required states.
3. Timing treading to scan status of all keys to decide how about the movement.